# Object has value when checked in console but show null when checked in controller (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am passing form object which has

```json
{
    form: {
        a: '',
        b: '',
        c: '',
        d: '',
        e: '',
        f: '',
        g: ''
    }
}
```

When I log it to see in console whether the values are null or not

```json
{
    a: "3"
    b: 2
    c: 2
    d: "5"
    e: "5"
    f: 2
    g: "4"
}
```

Nothing is null but after I do my axios post request like this

```js
axios.post('https://xyz/abc',this.form)
.then((res) => {
    // do something
});
```

One of the value is null automatically

When I `dd` in the controller, I get this:

```php
array:7 [
    "a" => "5"
    "b" => "5"
    "c" => "4"
    "d" => "3"
    "e" => 2
    "f" => 2
    "g" => null
]
```

Everything is present, except one value everytime.
I have matched my input field names already and I also think, that one value is not being set at all.
I am setting them as

```
<img id="b3" src="xyz"/>
```

setting in mounted function

```
mounted(){
let $vm= this;
$('#b3').click(function(){

  $vm.form.b= 3;
})
}
```

Comment: To log something at the exact time and place where the console log is and not when you view it, you might stringify complex values to "freeze" them before logging (usually done via `JSON.stringify()`).

Comment: I understand 
but i am logging them after everything has been set and on you can say on front end side every value is set but only one value gets null on reaching controller

Comment: That's right but other values also change ("a" changes von "3" to "5" for example)

Comment: Also, can you post your [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a little more comprehensive so that one can see the console.log and the data initialization?

Comment: No, nothing changes
its just the order
my point was to clarify the issue in question

Comment: JustCarty thank you for the editing but its not {
    form: {
        a: "3"
        b: 2
        c: 2
        d: "5"
        e: "5"
        f: 2
        g: "4"
    }
}


it is exactly like this as it is object

{…}
a: (...)
b: (...)
c: (...)
d: (...)
e: (...)
f: (...)
g: (...)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting the freeze concept from shaedrich's comment and i was assigning form at colliding time,
I set up onclick event rather than using jquery and assigned it in that function

Did this:

```
<img src="xyz" v-on:click="b(1)"/>
```

and in function i assigned it manually

```
b:function(n){
this.form.b= n
}
```